# How to define custom formatting ("faces") in org-mode for agenda lines by priority?

Tags: emacs, org-mode, text-formatting

I'm using org-mode 7.8.11 with Emacs 24.1.1 and I want to change the colors used to display agenda lines, so that e. g. all lines with priority "A" are shown in red bold font.

I tried to change the variable org-priority-faces but it has **no effect:**

```
 org-priority-faces is a variable defined in `org-faces.el'.
 Its value is (("A" :foreground "#E01B4C" :weight bold)
 ("B" :foreground "#1739BF")
 ("#C" :foreground "#575757"))
```

What am I doing wrong? Could other configurations overwrite this new setting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I customized variable `org-priority-faces` and it created the following line in my .emacs

```
(custom-set-variables
;; here there is customization for other variables 
    '(org-priority-faces (quote ((65 . "DeepPink") (66 . "firebrick") (67 . "tomato"))))
)
```

65, 66 and 67 are ASCII codes for **A, B** and **C** priorities.

Emacs displays colours correctly in agenda but only **[#A], [#B], ...** strings, not the whole line.

Comment: hm, thanks for your help. What do the numbers 65-67 in your example mean? I added the same to the end of my `.emacs`, did `eval-buffer`, but it had no effect at all on my agenda or org files.

Comment: I added more info to my answer. You can try to customize the variable using M-x customize-variable

Comment: INstead 0f 65, 66, 67 you can also use ?A, ?B, ?C to make it more readable.